# C++ coder for marks need help fixing it

Tags: c++

I was trying to learn c++ i wanted to find marks using the code the issue is that it is not giving me the correct output and i wanted it to loop if the marks are less i wawnted to repeat it .
This is the code that i wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

void mygrade(int grades)
{

    if (grades >= 90)
    {
        printf("High distinction");
    }
    else if (grades > 80 < 70)
    {
        printf("Your Grade is Distinciton");
    }
    else if (grades > 60 < 70)
    {
        printf("Credit");
    }
    else if (grades > 50 < 60)
    {
        printf("Pass");
    }
    else if (grades < 50)
    {
        printf("Fail");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter vaild Marks");
    }
}

void main()
{

    int grades;
    printf("Enter your score for this unit\n");
    scanf("%d", &grades);

    printf("your grade for this unit is: %d ");
}
```

[image: this is what i expecting to do]

Comment: `else if (grades > 80 < 70)` won't work. If you have multiple conditions you need to handle it like this `else if (grades > 80 && grades < 90)` which would be true for 81 to 89. You may want `>= 80` instead. You also need to call that function.

Comment: Those conditions aren't even mathematically valid.

Comment: By the way, your coditions, once fixed, will skip the values `80`, `70`,  `60` and `50` (they will end up in the `else` branch as invalid marks).

Comment: Note: If you check the limits in descending order, you don't need 2 checks per `if` since reaching the `else` branch already guarantes the previous condition evaluated to `false`, so you could write something like `if (grades >= 90) { ... } else if (grades >= 80){ ... } else if ...`

Comment: It's not a matter of **printing** an assessment; the assignment is that the function must **return** an assessment...

Comment: The signature of the `main` function is not one of the standard signatures of `main` btw: the permitted alternatives are `int main();` or `int main(int, char*[]);`; note `void main();` is absent. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function . Also the use of `#include <stdio.h> #include <stdbool.h> #include <string.h>` is concerning. Those includes should be `#include <cstdio> #include <cstring>` for C++, that is if you don't want to use the benefits of C++ and use `std::cout`/ `std::cin`...

Comment: What resources are you using, or classes are you taking, to learn C++? Because it looks like you're learning C and not C++. C and C++ are two very different languages. Learning C first doesn't really help with learning C++, because there are many thing you need to *unlearn* from C to learn C++ properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the program work as you write in the picture, there are three things to do:

1. You can just use

```
if (grades >= 90)
    // …
else if (grades >=80)
    // …
// and so on
```

since `else if` statement will be trigger only if all cases above it are not true.

2. You need to call `mygrade()` function in the `main()` function so that it will run.
3. If you want to repeat the program if the grades are less than 50, then you can use `do-while` loop.

```
do
{
    //…
}while (grades < 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is to use comparisons like "(grades > 80 < 70)", which is not allowed in C++.  Replace them with the form "((grades > 70) && (grades < 80))"

Comment: "Not allowed" is not correct; the conditions *are* allowed. They just do not do what is needed to make the code work in the expected way.

Comment: An expression of type `bool` is implicitly converted to values `0` or `1`, if the expression yields `false` or `true` respectively, therefore the condition is valid in C++, even though nonsensical.

Comment: @fabian basically, in above case the value (grades > 80 < 70) will always return true?

Comment: @Kraken Yes, since `<` and `>` are left-to-right.